# How can I programmatically generate documents using TeX?

Tags: web-services, tex

This applies to popular languages used for web development e.g. Python, Java, Rails etc.

I want to be able to programatically generate TeX documents. For example a user submits a form and a field contains the LaTeX code to be typeset and the web service returns the typeset PDF.

Are there libraries available for such a task? I can't find any.

The only other solution I can think of is to use external shell command functionality that's usually available. But this is a bit messy.

Comment: Does my answer below address your question?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I created [an Etherpad lite plugin](https://github.com/ulikoehler/ep_etherlatex) that allows you to compile the LaTeX serverside. [FlyLaTeX](https://github.com/alabid/flylatex) does it similarly, but didn't really work for me and the code looked pretty messy and almost impossible to fix and debug when I was having a look at it about 4 months ago.

Basically you need to generate a temporary file that you can then compile with LaTeX.

I don't know of any generation libraries, but LaTeX is quite easy to generate. However, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert different formats into LaTeX.

There is also https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/ which is an emscripten-based clientside port of LaTeX (that unfortunately has very limited capabilities and is quite large).